# windows opening on dual monitor open beyond the screen Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome

Tags: gnome, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I am on a laptop with a 1920x1080 built-in display, connected via mini-HDMI and an adapter to a VGA monitor 1600x900. Using Gnome as my DE.

When I open some windows (file browsing, image viewer) on the VGA monitor, they will open with the title bar extending above the monitor.

I can use the hotkeys to move or resize the window so that I can access that bar, but I would love to not have to do that. It's extra steps and it feels klunky.

I *think* that it's inheriting the window size from the primary display, but the behaviour doesn't seem consistent. When I change the file browser window size and then close it, *sometimes* it will retain that smaller size. (All of this is on the VGA display.) Other programs like the image viewer don't seem to have that behaviour.

I would love to know if there's an option I can't find that will make sure all windows open with their dimensions fitting the monitor that they're on, but I haven't found it yet!

Conversely, if I can get clarity on what the inheriting model is for windows sizes on different monitors, that would be great too!

Comment: You didn't say which DE you are using, but KDE (Kubuntu) has a "Window Rules" system settings module that lets you control *exactly* where a window is launched.

Comment: Ah! I'm using gnome. I should have flagged that!